# Like Twitter, I want to change the color of the like icon on every click

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making something like a Twitter like button.

I want to change the icon button color.

When clicking the button, changing from gray to red was successful.

But I don't know how to change it from red to gray.

I am using javascript and vue.

Below is the code I used.

```
<template>
  <div id="postbox">
    <div class="thumbnail-img" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + postItem.img + ')'}"></div>
    <div>
        <h4>{{postItem.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{ cutDescript }}</p>
        <div class="text-date">{{postItem.date}}</div>
        <hr>
        <div class="footer">
            <img class="profile-img" :src="postItem.profileImg"/>
            <span class="writer">by <span class="bold">{{postItem.writer}}</span></span>
            <b-icon icon="heart-fill" class="gap_margin_5px_horizontal"
                    :variant="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'danger' : ''"
                    v-on:click="greet('grid')"
            />
            <span class="good_num">{{postItem.good}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'postbox',
  props: {
      post: {
          type: Object,
          default: function () {
              return {
                  title: 'Undefined',
                  descript: 'This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.',
                  date: '----년 --월 --일',
                  profileImg: '../assets/logo.png',
                  writer: 'unknown',
                  good: 0,
                  img: '../assets/logo.png'
              }
          }
      }
  },
  data () {
    return {
        postItem: this.post,
        currentMode: this.mode
    }
  },
  computed: {
      cutDescript: function () {
          if (this.postItem && this.postItem.descript && this.postItem.descript.length >= 200) {
              return `${this.postItem.descript.slice(0, 197)}...`
          } else if (this.postItem && !this.postItem.descript) {
              return '본문이 비어있습니다.'
          }
          return this.postItem.descript
      }
  },
  methods: {
       greet: function (mode) {
           if (mode !== 'grid' && mode !== 'map') {
                mode = 'grid'
            }
            this.currentMode = mode
            this.$emit('current-mode', this.currentMode)
       }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the code to change the color in the double.

```
<b-icon icon="heart-fill" class="gap_margin_5px_horizontal"
    :variant="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'danger' : ''"
    v-on:click="greet('grid')"
/>
```

```
methods: {
       greet: function (mode) {
           if (mode !== 'grid' && mode !== 'map') {
                mode = 'grid'
            }
            this.currentMode = mode
            this.$emit('current-mode', this.currentMode)
       }
}
```

Gray is the default setting.

Red is 'danger'.

If you go to the following address, you'll find out more about what I'm talking about.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/color-variants

```
:variant="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'danger' : ''"
```

The part of the first code changes the color.

That changes when I click, I get a grid from the function.

When grid, the color changes to red.

So I think it is possible to return from red to gray by using conditional statements.

but it doesn't work as i want Is there any good way?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) + [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tagged VUE for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `:style="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'color:red;' : 'color:blue'"` instead `:variant`, and in method try

```
greet: function () {
  this.currentMode === 'grid' ? this.currentMode = '' : this.currentMode = 'grid'
}
```

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div id="postbox">
    <div class="thumbnail-img" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + postItem.img + ')'}"></div>
    <div>
      <h4>{{postItem.title}}</h4>
      <p>{{ cutDescript }}</p>
      <div class="text-date">{{postItem.date}}</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="footer">
        <img class="profile-img" :src="postItem.profileImg"/>
        <span class="writer">by <span class="bold">{{postItem.writer}}</span></span>
        <b-icon icon="heart-fill" class="gap_margin_5px_horizontal"
           :style="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'color:red;' : 'color:blue'"
           v-on:click="greet()"
        />
        <span class="good_num">{{postItem.good}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object,
      default: function () {
        return {
          title: 'Undefined',
          descript: 'This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.',
          date: '----년 --월 --일',
          profileImg: '../assets/logo.png',
          writer: 'unknown',
          good: 0,
          img: '../assets/logo.png'
        }
      }
    },
    mode: {type: String, default:''}
  },
  data () {
    return {
      postItem: this.post,
      currentMode: this.mode
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cutDescript: function () {
      if (this.postItem && this.postItem.descript && this.postItem.descript.length >= 200) {
        return `${this.postItem.descript.slice(0, 197)}...`
      } else if (this.postItem && !this.postItem.descript) {
        return '본문이 비어있습니다.'
      }
      return this.postItem.descript
    }
  },
  methods: {
   greet: function () {
     this.currentMode === 'grid' ? this.currentMode = '' : this.currentMode = 'grid'
     /*if (mode !== 'grid' && mode !== 'map') {
       mode = 'grid '
     }
     this.currentMode = 'grid'
     this.$emit('current-mode', this.currentMode)*/
   }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.js" integrity="sha512-Z0dNfC81uEXC2iTTXtE0rM18I3ATkwn1m8Lxe0onw/uPEEkCmVZd+H8GTeYGkAZv50yvoSR5N3hoy/Do2hNSkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.css" integrity="sha512-YnP4Ql71idaMB+/ZG38+1adSSQotdqvixQ+dQg8x/IFA4heIj6i0BC31W5T5QUdK1Uuwa01YdqdcT42q+RldAg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.css" integrity="sha512-i0tPmtwhNYyKmqYiccSN9qsEX25FsNNkeWqIbjYyk7QoVkPLfyl7QsABy3oIQx5ofROjV6KLJTzV+asMrT25UA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js" integrity="sha512-5czZ3eLMCVT2wJXRhx0yLN2TZzA2iuncwX2s3P1MTv3X8GHxfKRtcoaTkzEzM0g38iXyuYlES8kbfXNYe7zeTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child />
</div>
```

Comment: OMG. I did what you said and got the results I wanted! thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
:variant="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'danger' : 'gray'"
```

Or

```
v-bind:style="[currentMode == 'grid' ? {'color' : 'danger'} : {'color' : 'gray'}]"
```

**EDIT** 
Ok so in your function if the mode is not grid or is not map you say ok it's grid and set the current mode to grid. 
but you never change the mode to map. Am I right ? 
You can change this line of code like this :

```
<b-icon icon="heart-fill" class="gap_margin_5px_horizontal"
                    :variant="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'danger' : ''"
                    v-on:click="greet((currentMode == 'gird' ? 'map' : 'grid'))"
            />
```

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't change from red to gray because of the 'grid'.

Comment: Yes. I'm never change the mode to map. But as you said, the result is the same. But I found a workaround. Thanks for your help!